# how to duplicate MC in macromedia flash 8

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, macromedia

I'm having problems to duplicate movie clips in AS2. Can someone help me to get the general idea how I do this?

Comment: MM both of them. i get the idea of make a "x++" every time when i duplicate. but the problem is that i first open a menu which give the the opportunity to duplicate, so when i open this menu this "x" get again 0.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Can you post your code?

Comment: 'code'  this.onRelease=function(){
  trace(bedscount);
 duplicateMovieClip("bed1","bed1"+bedscount,100+bedscount);
 bedscount++;
 trace(bedscount);
  _root["bed1"+bedscount]._x = 480.6;
  _root["bed1"+bedscount]._y = 450.6;
 }

Comment: Ah, this code is executing within the scope of your button, so the bedscount variable is being newly created every time. On you root timeline declare the variable: `var bedscount:Number = 1;`, then in your function always refer to it using the root scope: `trace(_root.bedscount); _root.bedscount++;`

Comment: oooo ok! one problem solved! thank you very much!! but the bed doesn't appear i think that the problem is in the line: duplicateMovieClip("bed1","bed1"+_root.bedscount,100+_root.bedscount)

Comment: Yes, you're trying to use the global version of this function, and that doesn't seem to work as expected, although it also doesn't seem to return an error. Also, you're incrementing the counter and then trying to use it to position the button.  Try this instead: `this.onRelease=function(){  
 this.duplicateMovieClip("bed1"+_root.bedscount,100+_root.bedscount); 
 _root["bed1"+_root.bedscount]._x = 48; 
 _root["bed1"+_root.bedscount]._y = 45;
 _root.bedscount++;  
}`

Comment: it doesn't work...
maybe the problem is the depth?

Comment: It's working in the test I've built, where are you putting the code?

Comment: can I use the function attachMovieClip the same way?

Comment: there is a home screen where there is a button 'market' after clicking 'market' a new menu appears. there are beds and each bed is a MC. i put this code in those MCs. When clicking on one of the beds it should appear in the home screen & the menu disappear

Comment: attachMovie adds a movieclip from the library to the stage by using its linkage identifier.  So if you have a movieclip in the library with the linkage 'bed' then you would attach it to the current stage like this: `this.attachMovie("bed","myNewBed",depth);`

Comment: but in this way I can add only 1 MC' because they all will have the same name. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well yeah, that's just a basic example. Of course you will need the name and depth to be unique when creating multiple instances.  The problem you have here is that the scope of your application jumps around a bit.  This is a massive headache in AS2 if it's not managed carefully.  I think what's happening is that the duplicate is being attached to the menu rather than the home. It might help if you can update your question with the code you have on the home and in in the menu.

Comment: it all goes like that: pressing market button - on (release){
_root.attachMovie("shadow","newshadow",200);
_root.attachMovie("marketmen","newmarket",300);
}

Comment: than there is a new menu where we press beds - on (release){
 _root.attachMovie("bed_menu","bed_menu2",300);
}

Comment: than in this menu there are 2 beds. each is a movie clip. when I press on of them it should appear at the house. this.onRelease=function(){ trace(_root.bedscount); duplicateMovieClip("bed1","bed1"+_root.bedscount,100+_root.bedscount); _root.bedscount++; trace(_root.bedscount); _root["bed1"+_root.bedscount]._x = 480.6; _root["bed1"+_root.bedscount]._y = 450.6;

Comment: and the beds menu disapear- _root.newshadow.removeMovieClip(); _root.bed_menu2.removeMovieClip();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the IDE: Right click on a symbol in the library and select 'Duplicate'.

Now, code:

```
var duplicate:MovieClip = original.duplicateMovieClip("duplicateClip",this.getNextHighestDepth());
```

What you're doing here is calling the duplicateMovieClip function of your existing clip, telling it a name and depth for your new clip.  It returns a reference to the new clip, which is stored in the `duplicate` variable.

Comment: Alternatively, in the IDE you can use the shortcut: alt + drag